# Does ProcessModel impact WCF Window Services

Tags: wcf, machine.config

That could be a stupid question as ProcessModel is only used for IIS (as MSDN described), however, in my load testing, which a BizTalk app calling a windows service hosted WCF, I change the processModel from autoConfig to false, and set the minWorkThreads and maxWorkerThreads. The peroferamnce is magically improved... Did a bit google and still cannot understand the reason? Can anyone advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Since WCF Services use ASP.NET ThreadPool when you are exposing the service through IIS over HTTP/HTTPS, it is governed by the processModel, just like regular ASP.NET request are.

You can get the detail explanation of this behavior from here:

http://www.scottmillersnotes.com/?p=167

However, there's a bug in WCF 3.5's thread pool management due to which WCF services does not scale beyond a certain point. In WCF 4.0 that bug has been fixed. You can read the detail story and my exchange with Microsoft WCF team on this article for details:

http://omaralzabir.com/tweaking-wcf-to-build-highly-scalable-async-rest-api/

Helps?

Comment: what if the my WCF uses only NettcpBindings ? Will it still make a difference to tweak the processModel section in a windows service's app.config ?